# Vb.Net Get Mouse Coordinates from Listview Item

Tags: winforms, listview, point

I am trying to get mouse coordinates from a listview but it keeps saying that cant convert string to point. this is my code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        ListView1.Items(i).Selected = True

        Dim mMpos As String = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(i).SubItems(0).Text
        '  MsgBox(mMpos)



        '  Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(mMpos.X + 4 + Me.Location.X, mMpos.Y + Me.Location.Y + 23 )


    Next
```

listview has 3 set of coordinates like this   Item(0) is 100,100   Item(1) is  250,250    and last iten is (2) 300,300. each in there own items.

Comment: Well, for starters, mMpos IS a `string`, so I fail to see what you were expecting.

Comment: Even setting mMpos as point causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use mMpos.X, it raises an error because mMpos is a string and has no property named X. You can convert the string "100,100" (`ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(i).SubItems(0).Text`) to two strings of "100" and "100" using the string Split method, and then convert each of those to an integer or both of them to a point.